# Firmar apk en Android

Tags: android

Empezando con Android he visto que es necesario firmar la `apk`. Pero pensando en lo que es una firma digital y para qué sirve (garantizar autenticidad e integridad de información) he leido que realmente Android no te hace firmar las app para comprobar autenticidad e integración, sino que "Android utiliza esa firma para identificar a la aplicación que está realizando cualquier tipo de petición ya sea al sistema o a otras aplicaciones" http://www.uhurulabs.com/2013/07/firmando-aplicaciones-android

1. ¿Es así?
2. He leido que es recomendable que un desarrollador firme sus apps con la misma firma http://www.uhurulabs.com/2013/07/firmando-aplicaciones-android El concepto de firma digital es único para cada documento, con lo que ¿Cómo es posible que distintas apps de un developer tengan la misma firma?
3. Creo que he leido que al firmar el apk, solo yo puedo descrifarlo o decompilarlo ya que yo tengo la clave privada. ¿Es así?

Comment: En terminos de la vida real la firma permite que solo la persona que tiene la firma pueda hacer actualizaciones en la play store esto significa q si pierdes la firma la app ya no podra ser actualizada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La persona que escribió el artículo al que haces referencia tiene algunos problemas con el uso de terminología correcta, y termina diciendo algunas cosas sin sentido. Para aclararte, está la [documentación oficial del firmado](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Respondiendo a tus preguntas:

> ¿Es asi?

No. El sistema utiliza la firma del apk para lo que es, determinar la  autenticidad de acuerdo a la firma digital que contiene.

> He leido que es recomendable que un desarrollador firme sus apps con la misma firma

No, esto no sería posilbe. Lo recomendable es que un desarrollador firme sus apps con el mismo certificado. Al firmarlas con el mismo certificado podrá compartir funcionalidad y datos entre ellas, cosas que no son posibles para aplicaciones que no están firmadas con el mismo certificado.

> Creo que he leido que al firmar la apk, solo yo puedo descrifarla o decompilarla ya que yo tengo la clave privada. ¿Es asi?

No, cualquier persona con conocimientos intermedios puede obtener los .class a partir del dex y aplicar un *decompilador* a estos. La firma digital no está destinada ni pretende realizar ningún tipo de protección en este sentido.

Dicho todo esto, no necesitas un certificado emitido por autoridad de confianza para realizar el firmado de tus aplicaciones, puedes utilizar un certificado auto-emitido. Ya el análisis de si esto te conviene o no queda fuera del alcance de esta respuesta.

Comment: Pero en una comunicacion entre dos extremos, si ambos se conocen previamente, tiene sentido establecer un sistema de autenticidad para verificar que quien me envia algo es tal persona pero en este caso, el usuario final que descarga la aplicacion no sabe quien soy yo(el firmante de la aplicacion)  con lo cual no entiendo el sentido de firmar. Lo que quiero decir es que lo que puedes verificar es que la aplicacion tiene una firma y la firma "Entidad o persona que no conozco de nada". Entiendo que la integridad de la informacion tambien se comprueba

Comment: No es una firma en el sentido legal de la misma, y tampoco creo que tenga implicaciones legales. Es un uso, en mi opinión, válido, pero puramente técnico de la firma.

Comment: De allí que tenga sentido que se permitan los certificados auto-emitidos.