# ¿cual es el procedimiento para actualizar o publicar de nuevo mi app en playstore si no tengo la firma?

Tags: android, google-play

Hola necesito ayuda con la actualización de la app que desarrolle y google play publish no me deja subir la actualización. si lo subo como nueva aplicación me la elimina.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que mal asunto tienes entre manos. Si no tienes la misma firma (¿por qué no?), por seguridad Google no te va a dejar actualizar.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿cual es el procedimiento para actualizar o publicar de nuevo mi app
>   en playstore si no tengo la firma?

**Si no tienes el Keystore, desgraciadamente no podrás realizar una actualización de tu misma aplicación. Como opción es subir otra aplicación.**

Revisa estas respuesta:

[Recuperar llave publicación Aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8508/recuperar-llave-publicaci%C3%B3n-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android/8512#8512)

[Firmar apk en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33531/firmar-apk-en-android)